# How to follow JavaScript link via Selenium (no link text)

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, printing, scrape

I'm trying to complete a project at work where I automate getting the daily click counts of all our printers. The Canon iR5070 has a web interface, but it takes a few clicks to get to and I cannot execute link clicks or follows.

The link I want to follow is in this HTML.

```
<a href="javascript:load_device()" >
    <img src="en/media/bm10.gif" border="0", alt="Device Information", title="Device Information">
</a>
```

And if it helps, this is the javascript function in question:
The function:

```
function load_cdevice() {
    chgImg(5);
    var cgi_str = "en/pages/d_cbody.htm?";
    // for Expire Cache!!
    var now_time = new Date();
    cgi_str += "Dummy=" + now_time.getTime();
    parent.Body.location.href = cgi_str;
    }
```

Below is what I have unsuccessfully tried... (load_cdevice is the ultimate destination I want, since that is the page with the click counts, but I'm not sure if that's accessible from the landing page..)

```
def get_5070_info():
    print("Ripping info for Canon Imagerunner 5070")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get('http://10.0.0.34')

    # driver.implicitly_wait(3)
    assert "Remote UI" in driver.title

    # 'document.load_cdevice()
    # driver.execute_script('load_device()')
    # driver.execute_script('load_cdevice()')
    # driver.execute_script('javascript:load_device()')
    # driver.execute_script('javascript:load_device')
    # driver.execute_script('document.load_device()')
    # driver.execute_script("window.location = load_device()'")
    # driver.execute_script("window.location =avascript:load_device()'")
```

Any ideas or maybe an xpath that would get this link?  There is no link text in the href tag, just a img link.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To click on the link with title as **Device Information** you can use either of the following options :

- `CSS_SELECTOR`

  ```
  driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a > img[title='Device Information'][src='en/media/bm10.gif']").click()
  ```
- `XPATH`

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a/img[@title='Device Information' and @src='en/media/bm10.gif']").click()
  ```